# Extract info from mail using regex

Tags: c#, regex, email, extract

I want to extract some information from an email using regex in c#.

Here is a short snippet from the email:

```
...with mapi id 14.02.0387.000; Thu, 6 Feb 2014 09:09:33 +0100
From: site <site@company.dk>
To: "nonexistingmail@doesnotexist127.dk" <nonexistingmail@doesnotexist127.dk>
Subject: can this bounce
Thread-Topic: can this bounce
Thread-Index: Ac8jEr8t3k2RouQ1RaGPCXGFcE5oNg==Date:...
```

I want to extract the "from" address between the `<>`, the "To" address between `<>` and the subject (in the example, the subject is "can this bounce")

I'm not very familiar with regex, so I would appreciate any help.

(and btw, if there is a simpler more neat solution i'd be happy to hear!)

Comment: http://hpop.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using LINQ:

```
var fromAddress = new string(msg.SkipWhile(c => c != '<').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != '>').ToArray());

var toAddress = new string(msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf("To")).SkipWhile(c => c != '<').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != '>').ToArray());

var subject = new string(msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf("Subject")).SkipWhile(c => c != ' ').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != 'T').ToArray());
```

Comment: Very neat, and it Works! Only problem now is that the actual mail consists of MANY lines.. and the first lines to meet the requirements in the LINQ expression is actually not the correct ones, so I need to skip the first ones.. Is there a way to make it select the last lines in the string, instead of the first ones?

Comment: You can skip the first lines with `string.Substring`, for example `message.Substring(message.IndexOf("startFromHere"))`

Answer (score 1):

Full running example using regex:
I used **pattern** with 3 groups:
`@"[Ff]rom:[^<]*\<([^@]+@[^>]+)>[Tt]o:[^<]*\<([^@]+@[^>]+)>[Ss]ubject: ?(.*)Thread-Topic"`)

```
string source = "...with mapi id 14.02.0387.000; Thu, 6 Feb 2014 09:09:33 +0100From: site <site@company.dk>To: \"nonexistingmail@doesnotexist127.dk\" <nonexistingmail@doesnotexist127.dk>Subject: can this bounceThread-Topic: can this bounceThread-Index: Ac8jEr8t3k2RouQ1RaGPCXGFcE5oNg==Date:...";
Regex pattern = new Regex("[Ff]rom:[^<]*\\<([^@]+@[^>]+)>[Tt]o:[^<]*\\<([^@]+@[^>]+)>[Ss]ubject: ?(.*)Thread-Topic");
MatchCollection mc = pattern.Matches(source);
string partFrom = ""; string partTo = ""; string subject = "";
if(mc.Count>0)
{
    partFrom = mc[0].Groups[1].Value;
    partTo = mc[0].Groups[2].Value;
    subject = mc[0].Groups[3].Value;
}
Console.WriteLine("From: " + partFrom + " To: " + partTo + " Subject: " + subject);
```

I check if inside mail exist at sign (@) in my expression and extract all parts in single pattern.
If you want find **only mail addresses**, you can use this regex:

```
@"\<[^>@]+@[^>]+>"
```

Comment: I just tried your solution, but for some reason, the mc.Count is never > 0.. :(

Comment: I test my solution and I get this as result: `From: site@company.dk To: nonexistingmail@doesnotexist127.dk Subject: can this bounce` so it is not possible that you get a different result. I'm sure that you use a different input. Can you send the entire contents of the string `source` on which you tested it? .. or update your question and write what you tested already.

Comment: Hi Atiris, yeah I use a different inputstring. Didnt post it here because its quite long. Is it possible to send it using some mailsystem here, or how do you want it?

Comment: copy to your question (edit) new input string (only part before from until thread-index as in your first example), if you want general solution, we need more than 1 test case. and please paste there also part of your c# code you used for extract this parameters (if you modify my solution).

Answer (score 0):

\<(.*?)>

- \< : < is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it
  literally.
- (.*?) : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
- > : > is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it
  literally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in RegexBuddy with the .NET flavour using your source text, it breaks it into named capture groups so you can use match.Groups["FROM"].Value etc.

You can then iterate over the matches to determine if your matches contain a value from the specified capture group. I've used this approach before when matching documents which may be incomplete.

`(?:From: .+<(?<FROM>.+)>)?(?:To: .+<(?<TO>.+)>)?(?:Subject: (?<SUBJECT>.+))?`

Comment: Use in conjunction with Atiris' answer :)